# How can I delay inner for loop and make outer for loop to wait utill inner loop will finish iteration?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How can I do this?
How can I delay outer loop until inner for loop will finish taking in mind that I want to delay each inner for loop iteration for 2 seconds?
Result which I want to achieve:

outer loop prints in console: 0

outer loop awaits until inner loop will finish.

inner loop prints: 0, 1, 2 with 2 seconds delay.

then outer loop prints: 1.

outer loop awaits until inner loop will finish.

inner loop prints: 0, 1, 2 with 2 seconds delay.

And so on.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    alert(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
        alert(j);
      }
    }
```

Comment: So what you're really asking for are synchronous timeouts, yes?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37563825/4987197 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1776729/4987197

Comment: Use recursion, not loops. You then can easily continue asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Synchronous delay in code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921895/synchronous-delay-in-code-execution) you can have a wait function and include it in your code.

```
function wait(ms) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
  alert(i);
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    alert(j);
    wait(2000);
  }
}
```