# ES6/TypeScript Dynamic Imports - Slow launch time because of static imports (Nodejs CLI)

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, es6-modules

In my nodejs-code, I have replaced many `require(x)` with ES6 `import { ... } from "x"`.
Unfortunately, this is very bad for the launch time of my nodejs-CLI-program.

Let me first give you a little bit of background:

I have a nodejs-CLI-program that uses a whole bunch of external packages, but most of those packages are only required under rare circumstances (for example, if specific flags were passed to my program).
Those imports impose a significant overhead for the launch time of my program.
Even trivial commands like `myprogram --help` take more than one second because of those imports.

To fix this launch time problem, I would like to do "dynamic imports" for certain functionality.
In other words, I would like to import certain packages only if a specific functionality is actually needed by a given CLI-command.

With the old `require`-mechanics, this was trivially possible with a conditional call to `require`. However, I am not sure how to do this for modern TypeScript-code.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion for this kind of launch time problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Import Expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions) in TypeScript:

> Dynamic import expressions are a new feature and part of ECMAScript
> that allows users to asynchronously request a module at any arbitrary
> point in your program.
>
> This means that you can conditionally and lazily import other modules
> and libraries. For example, here’s an async function that only imports
> a utility library when it’s needed.

(In JavaScript, it's still a proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)

Example:

You have a main file and two dependencies.

```
./main.ts
./dependency-a.ts
./dependency-b.ts
```

Dependency 'a' will load fast.

```js
console.log('exporting dependency-a');

export const a = () => {
  console.log('called dependency-a');
};
```

While dependency 'b' will load slowly.

```js
console.log('exporting dependency-b');

// We'll emulate a slow synchronous task with a loop to add delay
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839049/4669212
function wait(ms: number) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    now = start;
  while (now - start < ms) {
    now = Date.now();
  }
}

wait(5000);

export const b = () => {
  console.log('called dependency-b');
};
```

In your main file, you call the exported functions conditionally, but the launch time will be slow because of dependency 'b', even if you just want to call dependency 'a':

```js
import { a } from './dependency-a';
import { b } from './dependency-b';

const run = (dep: 'a' | 'b') => {
  switch (dep) {
    case 'a':
      return a();

    case 'b':
      return b();

    default:
      console.log('do nothing');
  }
};

run();
```

What you can do is to use the dynamic import() expression like this:

```
const run = (dep: 'a' | 'b') => {
  switch (dep) {
    case 'a':
      return import('./dependency-a').then(({ a }) => {
        a();
      });
    case 'b':
      return import('./dependency-b').then(({ b }) => {
        b();
      });
    default:
      console.log('do nothing');
  }
};

run('a');
```

The slow dependency 'b' - and it's import statements, if there's any - will not be loaded when you run dependency 'a'. That means your CLI will have a better startup time.